# Complicated pivot in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have the following data structure, where value1 and value2 - some aggregated values for each segment and date(I can get unaggregated data, if it helps)

```
date segment value1   value2
---  ------  -------  ------
```

What do I need is a report,which looks like this:

```
            2015-01-01     2015-01-02   
         value1  value2  value1  value2
         ------  ------  ------  ------
segment1    19    5       18       7
segment2    20    5       21       7
```

for each date in a given period at the same time. How can I do that?

Comment: No one can find solution for you unless and otherwise you respond to us for what we are asking. Please make the question clear. @Trius

Comment: You provide no actual input and your output isn't an SQL result set (what are those day headings doing there)? It looks like you're trying to produce a table with a variable amount of columns -- something that isn't possible in an SQL query unless you're using dynamic SQL. Do you really need to do it in SQL? This is the kind of thing an Excel pivot table can do without breaking a sweat -- SQL, not so much.

Comment: You are right. OP isn't giving the actual source table and is pretty unclear. He is not even responding/replying for what we have asked. @Jeroen Mostert

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you want the segment followed by a sum of the columns Value 1 and value 2, if So here is an easy group to do that:

```
select segment
    , sum(Value1) as Value1
    , sum(value2) as Value2
From YourTable
group by segment
```

Comment: No, I need to see how  values are changing from date to date.

Comment: It's impratical to Present it in the hierarchical format your asking for, with a dynamic number of columns.You can have a dynamic number of columns based on parameters you select via Dynamic SQL, but it's probably not worth it when you could plop it into excel and pivot it in just a few seconds. However if your just doing this to improve your own skills Pinal Dave has an excellent article on the subject:

[Link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/03/28/sql-server-executing-dynamic-sql-sql-queries-2012-joes-2-pros-volume-4-query-programming-objects-for-sql-server-2012/)